# Does this "until" mean "before"?

Tags: meaning

I ran across the following sentences:

> On the other hand, a runnable process is always stored in exactly one
>   runqueue: no runnable  process  ever  appears  in  two  or  more 
>   runqueues. Therefore, **until** a process remains runnable, it is usually
>   bound to one CPU.

The above "until" means "before"? I suspect it means "while".

Comment: It is a typo.  It should be 'while'.

Comment: If there is a possibility of a typo, I believe so.

Answer (score 1):

Let me write down a sentence using each of the words **until**, **before**, and **while**, and I'll explain the meaning of each. I've simplified the sentence down because I don't know the context, "remains runnable" could mean "when all other processes have been run and this is the last one that *remains runnable*", or it could mean "until the process *finds itself runnable*"; so I'm not going to try to explain the meaning of the sentence, I'm just going to talk about its grammar.

> 1. Until a process is runnable, it is bound to one CPU.

Using the word 'until' implies that the process being bound to one-CPU is undesirable. The word 'until' implies a sense of time passing, so the process is *waiting* to become runnable.

> 2. Before a process is runnable, it is bound to one CPU.

This is the same as above, but it doesn't suggest that it would be desirable for the process to be runnable. Being non-runnable and bound to one CPU sounds just as good as being runnable and bound to more CPUs.

The word 'until' conveys a sense of time passing, but the word 'before' describes a fixed point in the past. Therefore, there's no sense of urgency that the process is waiting to become runnable.

> 3. While a process is runnable, it is bound to one CPU.

This actually means the exact opposite of the above two sentences! It's saying that *after* the process has gone from non-runnable to runnable, it is *now* bound to one CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Until a process remains runnable, it's usually bound to one CPU.

No,  until doesn't mean before in the sentence.  You usually use until in the sense of before when the main clause is in the negative. 
For example, you cannot pass the test until you work hard.

The conjunction "until" in the sentence presented in the question conveys the sense of 'up to the time that".

Comment: Thank you. But for me, 'up to the time that' and 'before' looks like a same thing.